# Use Regex to capture first part, skip middle, and capture last part

Tags: regex

I've some lines like the example below, I want to capture everything in the first bracket, then everything in the `some texts` part.

`{Foo} - {Bar} - some texts`

Expected result: `{Foo} - some texts`

All the texts and the ones in the brackets will be different, so I will need to based it off on the `{}` and `-` to capture what I need.

What I've came up with gets everything in the first bracket, `\{(.*?)\}`. However I'm not too sure how I can skip the middle part and just grab the `some texts`. I'm looking at using lookaround assertions, is that the best way to approach this?

Thanks.

Comment: You must be able to replace `" - .* - "` with `" - "` (without quotes)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Exactly. You are correct, sir

Answer (score 1):

## Use 2 Capture Groups to Exclude the Middle

> ```
>  /(\{.+?\})\s-\s\{.+?\}\s-\s(.+?)\b/gi;
> ```
>
> <sup>☝                                               ☝</sup>
>                    <sup>Replace from here to ..........................there with \s-\s</sup>

This pattern will match multiples on the same line and/or multiple lines.

---

### Demo

```js
var str = `{Foo} - {Bar} - some text
{Foo} - {Bar} - some different text
{Foo} - {Bar} - this text is always matched correctly because the word boundary at the end {Foo} - {Bar} - so this pattern is ok sharing the same line and/or
{Foo} - {Bar} - multiple lines`;

var rgx = /(\{.+?\})\s-\s\{.+?\}\s-\s(.+?)\b/gi;

var res = str.replace(rgx, '$1 - $2');

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in perl, it is skipping everything up to and including `.+\} -` then matching whatever is left:

```
$ cat x.pl
use strict;

my $str = '{Foo} - {Bar} - some texts';

if ($str =~ /\{(.*?)\}.+\} - (.+)/) {
    print "$1, $2\n";
}


$ perl x.pl
Foo, some texts
```

Answer (score 0):

Following regex should work as `/({[^}]+})(?:.+})?(.+)/` with `capture group 1` containing **{Foo}** and `capture group 2` has **some text**